# disabled htaccess for selected directory

Tags: .htaccess

i have a htaccess code shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/host
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/host/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
```

but it still read the htaccess in `administrator` folder. is the code incorrect?
Thanks.

Comment: We can't tell whether the code is incorrect as long as you don't tell us what it's supposed to do. :)

Comment: i just want the htaccess is disabled for administrator folder..

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled" exactly. Do you have a second htaccess in the administrator folder? Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: no, i don't. i have some problem if the administrator still read the htaccess, so want to disabled it, just that

Comment: Try `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `$1`

Comment: i already change to `%{REQUEST_URI}`, but the administrator still read the .htaccess file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` statements apply to *one* `RewriteRule` only.

You need to repeat your `RewriteCond`s for the second rewrite rule (and use `REQUEST_URI`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/host
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/host/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/host
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
```

Comment: whoa, thanks alott.. but there is some problem appear, now the localhost/host doesn't read the .htaccess :(

Comment: @KaLv1n I'm not sure what is happening, but try `localhost`, remove the `/host`